# Is okhttp secure to use for registration and login purposes?

Tags: android, okhttp, java

Im creating an app that requires user registration and login,
is it ok to use Okhttp for that purposes?

if not, What are the alternatives?

Comment: OkHttp is an http client. I'd say security depends more on the way you're implementing it. If https is enough, then OkHttp should be fine. I don't know exactly what kind of requirements you're seeking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OkHttp can be used securely. You need to use TLS and keep both OkHttp and your server up-to-date. In particular OkHttp [curates what’s allowed](https://square.github.io/okhttp/tls_configuration_history/) for TLS with each release .